# C# XPATH with namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

This is the XML-file, I want to get the Xpath for **cron-expression**, actually I want to change the inner text. I have tried many methods but nothing works and I just want to get the direct answer.
I have tried like local-name and `XmlnamespaceManager.addnamespace`, but it does not work.

```
<!-- This file contains job definitions in schema version 2.0 format -->

<job-scheduling-data 
xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">

  <processing-directives>
    <overwrite-existing-data>true</overwrite-existing-data>
  </processing-directives>

  <schedule>

    <job>
        <name>SampleJob</name>
        <group>SampleGroup</group>
        <description>My job</description>
        <job-type>Quartz.Server.SampleJob, Quartz.Server</job-type>
        <durable>true</durable>
        <recover>false</recover>
    </job>

    <trigger>
     <cron>
        <name>SampleTrigger</name>
        <group>SampleGroup</group>
        <description>Simple trigger to simply fire sample job</description>
        <job-name>SampleJob</job-name>
        <job-group>SampleGroup</job-group>
        <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
        <cron-expression>0 * 15 * * ?</cron-expression>
      </cron>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

This is my code:

```
 protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load("D:/Chrome/Quartz.NET-2.4.1/src/Quartz.Examples/quartz_jobs.xml");
        XmlNamespaceManager xnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        xnm.AddNamespace("h", 
"http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData");

   XmlNode XN = doc.SelectSingleNode("h:job-scheduling-data/h:schedule/h:trigger/h:cron/h:cron-expression",xnm);


 //     XmlNode XN = doc.SelectSingleNode("/*[local-name() = 'job-scheduling-data']/*[local-name() = 'schedule']/*[local-name() = 'trigger']/*[local-name() = 'cron']/*[local-name() = 'cron-expression']");
    XN.InnerText = "0";
    doc.Save("D:/Chrome/Quartz.NET-2.4.1/src/Quartz.Examples/quartz_jobs.xml");//
}
```

Comment: Why do you have all those `h:` prefixes in your xpath when the elements in your xml don't have it?

Comment: @NtFreX it was the same consequence if i remove those  `h:` , i was trying different kinds of approaches because im not familiar with XML files

Comment: When I copy the xml you have in your question and then take the xpath from `SelectSingleNode` without all the `h:` I get the correct element.

Comment: @NtFreX really!! ? can you show me the code ? i have suffered from this for a long time....

Comment: @NtFreX It's not work with me , i deleted all the `h:`, and it shows `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: I've posted the code which works on my end. Maybe also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it is working with the xml you posted. In case the element can be found noting will be done to the saved xml.

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("D:/Chrome/Quartz.NET-2.4.1/src/Quartz.Examples/quartz_jobs.xml");

var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("x", "http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData");

XmlNode selectedNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("x:job-scheduling-data/x:schedule/x:trigger/x:cron/x:cron-expression", namespaceManager);
if (selectedNode != null)
{
    selectedNode.InnerXml = "0";
    doc.Save("D:/Chrome/Quartz.NET-2.4.1/src/Quartz.Examples/quartz_jobs.xml");
}
```

Comment: can you post the XML file after manipulation. I think you did not change the `InnerText` successfully because if `selectdNode` is null, it will execute the `else` case

Comment: @muxingwang If the element cannot be found nothing will be done. This can only be possible if the read xml is not like the one you posted in your question.

Comment: @muxingwang I meant the xml not the code. Look at the xml file. It must be different to the xml you posted.

Comment: The XML file i posted is with some namespace , i think the namespaces break the normal XPATH. Can you new a XML file and copy my file to it to test your code?

Comment: @muxingwang I had mistakenly taken the default namespace out. I've updated the answer. Like so it works on my end.